# Spring: REST exceptions are caught as 403 Forbidden exception

Tags: java, spring, exception

I created a Spring Boot Rest Api with custom JWT authentication (that I'll change someday with Keycloak).

The custom filter is this:

```
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JwtService jwtService;

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            @NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
            @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
            @NonNull FilterChain filterChain
    ) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        final String jwt;
        final String userEmail;
        if(authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")){
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
        // Extract token
        jwt = authHeader.substring(7);
        // Extract username or email from JWT token
        userEmail = jwtService.extractUsername(jwt);
        if(userEmail != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null){
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userEmail);
            if(jwtService.isTokenValid(jwt, userDetails)){
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails,
                        null,
                        userDetails.getAuthorities()
                );
                authToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

The security configuration:

```
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{
        
        httpSecurity
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
    
}
```

The problem is that when I encounter any exception during runtime (IllegalArgumentException, RuntimeException etc.) all of them are returned to the caller as a "403 Forbidden".
I want to return the actual exception to whoever made the call.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Where is your security configuration?

Comment: @Unmitigated added to the question, sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to allow access to `/error`.

```java
.requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**", "/error").permitAll()
```

Comment: It's now returning a "500 Internal server error" but I guess that's ok, I can make an exception handler to handle and return the error messages as I want.

Does this means that the security configuration returns an HTTP response with the "/error" path to the caller?

Comment: @FedericoArona `/error` is just the path Spring uses to handle all errors.

Comment: Cool. thanks. I still don't understand why if I don't allow access to "/error", it returns "403" since the request I'm making has the auth header in it, but I'll figure it out.